# How many ways are there to roll a pair of dice 10 times so that every double (i,i) is rolled at least once.

Tags: probability

As in the title:
We roll a pair of dice 10 times.
How many ways are there to do that such that every pair $(i, i)$ (for $i={1,2,3,4,5,6}$) appears at least once?

Comment: This seems like a homework question. That is fine, but the community may be more inclined to help if you provide examples of what you have tried yourself.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your post to include your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: $6!\sum_{i=30}^{36} i\sum_{j=i}^{36} j\sum_{k=j}^{36} k\sum_{m=k}^{36} m$  If it is reopened, I'll give details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use inclusion - exclusion principle

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{6}{\binom{6}{i}(36-i)^{10}(-1)^{i}}
$$

Comment: Please do not answer questions when the person posing the question has not shown an attempt to solve it.

Comment: @Rezha Adrian Tanuharja How do you get this result?

Comment: By considering the probability of some pair (i,i) not appearing within the first 10 rolls.

Comment: Except the sum should start at 1.

Comment: @Dood when $i=0$, we get $36^{10}$ i.e. all possible result. and that is the idea, calculate all possible result and subtract results with at least a pair missing.

Comment: You are of course correct, I forgot to come back to calculating the original probability.

Comment: I can't tell whether your answer agrees with mine.  However yours is much harder to calculate.  For 6 (rather than 10)  rolls I get $6!$ immediately.